# UIViews not changing background color

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, background-color

Ive placed two uiviews in my main view however i cannot change their color

```
self.newView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255 green:237.0f/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0];
```

What am i doing wrong?

**solved******
moved code to

viewDidAppear

Comment: Show how you are adding the views. The code you have provided is not enough to identify the issue

Comment: Are you sure the outlets are connected? Or are the views added in code?

Comment: @MattLong just checked the outlets are connected

Comment: @bengoesboom views are added through storyboard outlets

Comment: In what method are you trying to set the background color?  Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The color you set is nearly similar to the default one. That's why I think you got confused. Please change the color to [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:0/255 blue:246.0f/255 alpha:1.0];

You will see a blueish color. I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.newView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:237.0f/255.0f blue:246.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

I reckon it's because you're not dividing by a float value and it's casting to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I switched the code to `viewWillAppear`